# How to compare and sort 2 csv's to show difference

Tags: bash, awk

Hi I have 2 csv's in the following format, (basically a list of email and the number of times we have been emailed by that sender):

file1.csv

```
Email,Value     
email1@email.com,2    
email2@email.com,4    
email3@email.com,1    
email4@email.com,6
```

file2.csv

```
Email,Value    
email1@email.com,3    
email2@email.com,6    
email3@email.com,8    
email4@email.com,2
```

the values in each table might be different and what I want to do is output the results to a new CSV which looks like this:

file3.csv

```
Email,Value1,Value2    
email1@email.com,2,3    
email2@email.com,4,6    
email3@email.com,1,8    
email4@email.com,6,2
```

I've got a `bash` script that I took from elsewhere and it does part of the job but It doesnt list the results I am looking for.

Can anyone help with a bash script for this?

```
#!/bin/bash

join -t"," -1 1 -2 1 -a1 file1.csv file2.csv | awk -F, ' BEGIN {  
    print "Email,Value"  
} NF > 3 {  
    if ( $3 != $5 )  
        print $1, $3, $5  
    if ( $2 != $4 )  
        print $1, $2, $4  
} ' OFS=,
```

This is the result I am getting by using the following:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","; printf "Name,Value1,Value2\n"}NR >1 && 
FNR==NR{map[$1]=$2; next}$1 in map{$(NF+1)=map[$1]; print}' file2.csv 
file1.csv
```

Results:

```
Name,Value1,Value2
,3ail1@email.com,2
,6ail2@email.com,4
,8ail3@email.com,1
Email4@email.com,6,2
```

Comment: Can you show us some sample values for each and an _exact_ output you need of that

Comment: Can you post what you have tried too?

Comment: You have a typo in file1, line number replace the `,` with a dot, `email4@email,com,6` to `email4@email.com,6`

Comment: In case `file1` and `file2` don't have the same email addresses, what is the output?

Comment: in the awk inline script $1 to $5 refers to index starting at 1 of string array which result after splitting the line with `,` argument option `-F` but the input which is the output of join there are only 3 fields

Comment: man, remove the MessyDos line endings... `\r` from your files.

Comment: to do what @jm666 suggests, run `dos2unix` or similar. You show the same email addresses in both files - do you never get a new email address appearing in a file that wasn't in a previous file (or vice-versa)? You show all the email addresses in the same order in both files - can they never be in different orders? If any of those can happen then include those cases in your example so we can see how you want that handled.

Answer (score 1):

using `join` program

```
join -t, -o0,1.2,2.2 -a1 -a2 <(sort <file1.csv) <(sort <file2.csv)
```

otherwise if files are already sorted and contain the same entries
with bash builtins

```
while
    IFS=, read -u3 em1 val1
    IFS=, read -u4 em2 val2
    [[ -n $em1 ]] && [[ -n $em2 ]]
do
    if [[ $em1 = $em2 ]]; then
        echo "$em1,$val1,$val2"
    else
        echo "ERROR: $em1 <> $em2"
    fi
done 3<file1.csv 4<file2.csv
```

Comment: I get this error with the join script you wrote:

Name,Value1,Value2                                             
awk: can't open file file2                              
 source line number 1

Comment: I've fixed it now, copied the code exactly as it is, it runs but doesnt give the expected output. I just get: email2@email.com,32

nothing else

Comment: the bash script assumes all entries are the same and in the same order : it open file1 on fd3 and file2 on fd 4 and read one line from each file and if the first field is equal echoes the merged line, the script is given as example and should be understood

Comment: I've just added an error message to help to understand what it is doing

Comment: you don't need the redirection for `sort` commands `<(sort file)` would do.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty *straight-forward* with `Awk`!

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","; printf "Name,Value1,Value2\n"}NR >1 && FNR==NR{map[$1]=$2; next}$1 in map{$(NF+1)=map[$1]; print}' file2 file1
```

produces

```
Name,Value1,Value2
email1@email.com,2,3
email2@email.com,4,6
email3@email.com,1,8
email4@email.com,6,2
```

Set input and output field-separator to `,` in the `BEGIN` clause that gets executed before the input lines are processed and also the *final* header information needed. The part `FNR==NR` is run for the first file in order `file2` in this case, create a hash-map, with an index set to the `$1` and value set to `$2` then on `file1` for those lines whose hashed index value belongs in `$1` create a new field `$(NF+1)` meaning the last field + `1` to the new value and print the result formed.

Comment: Name,Value1,Value2
awk: can't open file file2
 source line number 1

Comment: @snowblind: Change file1 and file2 to your actual csv file names?

Comment: this is the output that give:

Comment: Name,Value1,Value2

Comment: @snowblind: It means your input file is not in the format as you indicated in the question. Because it worked perfectly fine on your input provided

Comment: there was some format saving issues which i've just fixed.

Comment: Now I get the following output. still a little off 
edit in my post to see the result

Answer (score 1):

if you want to keep the order

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk  'BEGIN   {FS=OFS=","}
        NR==FNR {a[$1]=$2; next} 
        FNR==1  {print $1,$2"1",a[$1]"2"; next} 
                {print $1,$2,a[$1]}' file2 file1

Email,Value1,Value2
email1@email.com,2,3
email2@email.com,4,6
email3@email.com,1,8
email4@email.com,6,2
```

note the order of files...

Answer (score 0):

1. build a loop running through each line from the first file.
2. in that loop, build another loop comparing each line of the second file to the current line of the first file.
3. write matches to your new file.